# Gitlab CI push to docker-registry fails

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have GitLab server and a separate `docker-registry`. I have created a `testuser` with a `testpassword`.

My  `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:18.09.7-dind
    
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    # See https://github.com/docker-library/docker/pull/166
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  REGISTRY: myregistry:5000/golang-test

stages:
  - build
 # - test
before_script:
  - docker login -u testuser -p testpassword  myregistry:5000

build_project:
    stage: build
    tags:
      - docker-ci
    script:
      - docker ps
      - docker build -t $REGISTRY .
      - docker push $REGISTRY
```

When CI pipeline runs, I get following error.

> WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use
> --password-stdin. Error response from daemon: Get https://myregistry:5000/v2/: dial tcp: lookup worker1 on
> 192.168.123.456:53: no such host ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "docker-ci"
  url = "https://gitlab.sample.com:8000/"
  token = "89MfxRTby83ny3eTkTf2"
  tls-ca-file = "/etc/gitlab-runner/certs/gitlab.sample.com.crt"
  executor = "docker"
  pre_build_script = "export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2375"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "ubuntu:18.04"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

This was after suggested modifications [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/9359/gitlab-ci-error-during-connect-get-http-docker2375-v1-40-containers-jsonall).

I can successfully login to my `docker-registry` using `docker login -u testuser -p testpassword  https://myregistry:5000` from gitlab running server.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that your registry is publicly available?
Checklist:

- Check if the domain is reachable and responding the right IP address -- `nslookup myregistry`
- Check if your port is open or not blocked any kind of software (let's say via firewalls or AWS security group) -- `telnet myregistry 5050`
- Check if your registry is not restricted for a particular CIDR of IP
- Test your login locally and ensure that there is no problem with it